# C# Send email using SMTP

Tags: c#, smtp

> Exception :
>
> > Failure sending mail.
>
> Inner Exception:
>
> > Unable to connect to the remote server.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.Subject = "Your Subject";
mail.From = new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com");
mail.To.Add("xyz@yahoo.co.in");
mail.Body = "Hello! your mail content goes here...";
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
NetworkCredential netCre = new NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com", "xxx");
smtp.Credentials = netCre;

try
{
     smtp.Send(mail);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 }
```

I ping `smtp.gmail.com` it works fine.

Comment: Does your application have permissions to use internet?

Comment: Have you checked firewall settings? I had the same problem once and it turned out it was blocked by my firewall.

Comment: try using port 25 instead of 587 since you are using ssl https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en

Comment: If you use gmail please log into your account and change in settings to accept connecting to remote server by other apps

Comment: mark can u say about firewall settings like its seems to be fine on my side

Comment: You cannot use gmail smtp like this. You may be able to send couple of emails when you attempt for the first few times. After that gmail smtp will block you. Use your own smtp server instead.

Comment: Try adding these: `smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network` and `smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false`.

Comment: That error basically means that a TCP connection could not be established between your machine and the remote host. Therefore you have a connectivity issue. You should focus on that part. Check your firewall (even if ping works (icmp echo request), that does not mean tcp should). Or perhaps you tried too many times and your IP got banned by Google. If you have a dynamic IP, try resetting your connection to obtain a new one and give it anorher try.

Comment: Try `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` see if that connects. Should receive a much similar response like this: `220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP o1-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.151 - gsmtp`

Answer (score 2):

```
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(); 

mm.From = new MailAddress("From", "DisplayName", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
mm.To.Add(new MailAddress("To"));
mm.Subject = "Subject";
mm.Body = "Body";

mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
if (ccAdd != "")
{
    mm.CC.Add(ccAdd);
}
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
NetworkCred.UserName = "xyz@gmail.com";//gmail user name
NetworkCred.Password = "Password";// password
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
smtp.Port = 587; //Gmail port for e-mail 465 or 587
smtp.Send(mm);
```

It will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Hint for windows 7 / visual studio 2019 developers: The code below doesn't work with .NET 4.8.03761 but with .NET 4.6.1              < 08.11.2022>
It works on windows 10 / visual studio 2022 and .NET 4.8.04084
-> I reimported the file from windows 10 to windows 7 and then choosed for the reimport environment .NET 4.6.1 !!!

```
private void btnSendEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage Mail = new MailMessage();
    
    Mail.From = new MailAddress("anyone.name@gmx.de");
    Mail.To.Add("anyone_else.name@gmx.de");
    Mail.Subject = "This is a test email from a C# program.";
    Mail.Body = "win7_ABCDEFG----hgfgfhgfhgjjhköhökhgjhfhgfhgk\nhgjgjhgjhgj";
    // Mail.Bcc.Add("otto.waalkes@gmx.de");       // choose here additionaly anyone
    // Mail.CC.Add("....");

    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("mail.gmx.net");   //  also: mail.gmx.de

    smtpClient.Port = 587;                                      // 587;    also:  25
    smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("anyone.name@gmx.de", "password/2022");
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;     // recomended for SSL encryption with 465 -> doesn't work
    
    // https://www.wolfgang-frank.eu/mailserver.php    a long list of german mailserver

    try
    {
        smtpClient.Send(Mail);                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Beep();
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correction:
Hint for windows 7 / visual studio 2019 developers: The code below doesn't work with **.NET 4.7.2**    (Visual Studio 2019 /poject explorer / project / rigth mouse / properties / target framework) but with .Net 4.6.1

Additional, I had to set in the E-Mail browser of the sender - here anyone.name@gmx.de / left down - "Einstellungen"(settings) / "POP3/IMAP Abruf"  /   "das Häckchen" (the check mark)     X    "GMX Mail über POP3 & IMAP erlauben"      <18.12.2022>

Answer (score -3):

Email Script By ASP.Net

```
//mail script
           string name = TextBox1.Text;
           string email = TextBox3.Text;
           string feedback = TextBox5.Text;
           System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
           message.To.Add("info@globalestcon.com");
           message.Subject = "Email from website";
           message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email);
           message.Body = feedback;
           System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("relay-hosting.secureserver.net");
           smtp.Send(message);
           TextBox1.Text = "";
           TextBox2.Text = "";
           Response.Write("<script>alert('Form Submitted');</script>");
```

I hope it will help you. its working

Comment: This doesn't help at all, OP already has correct code, but something else is blocking it.